# The given path's format is not supported. when passing path what kind of path we have to pass

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have to write file on perticuler path of c drive i used following code it is givin above error The given path's format is not supported.

My path Value is D:\Ea\10\rep\Demo.txt

```
 System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, string.Empty);
        StreamWriter file2 = new StreamWriter(path, true);
        file2.WriteLine("Demo");
 file2.Close();
if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
System.IO.File.Copy(path, @"D:\Demo.htm", true);
```

Comment: My path Value is D:\Ea\10\rep\Demo.txt

Comment: Shouldn't it be `@path`? I don't think appending your path to the symbol @ will do much.

Comment: @user2996030: are you able to run your code?

Comment: There could be a typo: you tell here, your path is "d:\eA\..." and in a comment you write that access to "d:\eD\..." is denied. Have a look on that.

Comment: i think that is typo as specified in comments below `@Dylan Corriveau` Answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, string.Empty);
```

You wouldn't append a @ symbol to the path. You should be able to just put in the path value (depending on what it is).

E: You just said in your comments its D:\Ea\10\rep\Demo.txt , but the error is 'D:\ED\10\Res\Demo.txt' is denied? Maybe its because the file names are a bit off?
trying changing the path value

Comment: i would like to add a point: @ Symbol is used in front of a string to specify that given path is intact(take as it is)'

Comment: now this is coming Access to the path 'D:\ED\10\Res\Demo.txt' is denied.

Comment: @Dylan: i think it might be  OP's typo, if the path does not exit it throws : could not find path exception IMO

Comment: @user2996030: showing more lines from your code helps us to resolve the issue.

Comment: @user2996030 ah ok. Still. Is it possible for you to show us a bit more of your code? possibly where you define the path, and where you use it?

Comment: @user2996030: i think there is no problem with the code but some time if the streamwriter is not disposed properly it can happen IMO, can u check my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no problem in the code but if your `StreamWriter` is not disposed properly then you need to face some issues.so it is good to move your `StreamWriter` inside `using{}` block so `StreamWriter` willbe disposed as soon as it finishes the Writing.

Try This:

```
            String path=@"D:\Ed\10\rep\Demo.txt";
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, string.Empty);
            using (StreamWriter file2 = new StreamWriter(path, true))
            {
                file2.WriteLine("Demo");
            }
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                System.IO.File.Copy(path, @"D:\Demo.htm", true);
```

Comment: I agree. You should be trying to use the using predicate when you can. It can do all the opening/closing for you.

Comment: Thanks, yes a class which implements IDisposable Interface can be kept inside the using block so that disposing will be taken care without user intervention.

Comment: @user2996030: do you have the admin rights from where you are running the aplication?